# 2 quick questions about passing by const pointer/const reference

Tags: c++, reference, pointers, constants

1) Can someone explain the following?

```
void OnCreate(HWND hWnd, const LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
   lpCreateStruct->x = 2; // this compiles
}

void OnCreate(HWND hWnd, const CREATESTRUCT * lpCreateStruct)
{
   lpCreateStruct->x = 2; // this does not compile
}
```

2) Is it faster to pass by pointer or by reference? Or the same?

Comment: I could compile because i specify const, and am trying to change it in the function

Comment: gcc gives me an error for your const my_structure* function... what compiler are you using? Any special settings?

Comment: The code I posted didn't actaully compile (which was what I wanted).

Here, I edited my first post with the code that is actually in my program. Any ideas?

Comment: In general, you should post each question separately.

Answer (score 5):

`const LPCREATESTRUCT` expands to `CREATESTRUCT* const`, i.e. a constant pointer to non-const structure, while
 `const CREATESTRUCT*` is a non-constant pointer to constant structure, so the compiler is right.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the following assign 2 to x
>   when it is const?

It shouldn't, any standard-compliant compiler makes that an error because `ms` points to a `const my_structure`.

*edit:*

With your updated case, its a problem of how typedefs work:

```
typedef T* TPtr;

void f(const TPtr);
void g(T* const);
void h(const T*);
```

Both `f()` and `g()` are equivalent and take a `const` pointer to a `T`, while `h()` a pointer to a `const T`.

Comment: yea, i tested myself. the code I posted actually didnt compile so I edited with my own code